# What's a best way to store a lot of data in cache?

Tags: php, xml, caching, curl

My website sends curl requests to an external service and gets XML responses.
The requests are user specific and the responses are rather heavy (& several requests on the same page), so it takes time to load the page and uses too much server's traffic.

How I tried to solve the problem:

- The requests sent from the client side (js). Unluckily for me it becomes rather messy to parse the received data and integrate it to the page's objects
- Put the responses in session (as they are specific for user). The session files on server get large too fast. Implemented a counter, that erases all the responses from session if their number is too big (using this now)
- Memcache? Too much data to save

Do you think I should use one of the solutions or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Then give different keys for diff category of data to store in cache

Comment: @Gautam3164: How does it solve the problem, there are too many users and different requests, still it will take too much space, and it will be much slower to get data from session

Answer (score 0):

Use a commbination of

- cache
- database

You push things in your "data store" (this is cache and database). Then you look up in your datastore if it is available. The data store looks into cache, if available give it, if not look in database. And if everything fails get the info.

You could also increase the size of the cache (but that is not a good sollution).

Comment: do you mean memcache? I think, it is too much data for it:((

Comment: There are a lot of different caches available, but memcached is widly used for the task

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$key = "User_id_".$user_id."category_".$category_id;
```

then acc to this key store each data like

```
$memcache->set($key, $data, , 3600);
```